# How to identify API requests coming from a specific user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-analytics

I'm creating this API that is going to receive data from sites. Just like Google Analytics (not really).

I have the following model:

```
class Site < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :metrics
end
```

My API also has an endpoint that the client will send data to. Right now, this endpoint is not protected and any person can send data to it. I'm wondering if it is possible somehow to identify that the data is coming from the actual site, and not someone sending it from postman, for example. I know that Google Analytics does not require a key, you just install the snipped on a website and you are good to go.

Would it be possible to filter requests based on a parameter that only the real website would have?

Comment: What do you mean "Google Analytics don't require a key"? When you copy and paste the pre built javascript it already includes the "key" but it still requires one.

Comment: There are plenty of ways. you can add `X-BK-AUTH` key in request headers. One secret key based on that you can identify whether its authenticated or not.

Comment: If you would also share how your client side code will collect and send these metrics to your API that could help in providing you with a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I got your question.

You want to filter requests that only allow the real website to be processed.

In your controller, you can check the request's user agent with `request.env['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`. You can create a blacklist or whitelist to process the requests. However, there are plenty of user agents.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend implementing tokens with your API if you'd like to have security and control over any of your exposed endpoints. [Devise-JWT](https://github.com/waiting-for-dev/devise-jwt) is one well thought out solution to checkout.